# .gitignore not ignoring a folder within a directory

Tags: github

It seems a straightforward one, but having researched multiple ways to do it, I can't gitignore a folder within a directory.

I have a root directory which contains all of my code in it. Because it has some back-end NodeJS stuff in it, it has a 'node_modules' folder which contains hundreds of files. As a result, when I try to upload the entire parent folder, GitHub says there's too many files to upload and tells me to reduce the number I'm uploading.

The crucial part is though, the folder has to be uploaded as a whole, as it itself is within a GitHub repository with other files with different folders in.

That means when I go onto my repository, I need this folder's files to display within the folder, and not separately within the repository. I need all of the files to be within this folder, within the parent repository, excluding the node_modules folder.

For example ->

Parent repository -> Child Directory (what I'm uploading) -> Individual files

I've tried to add the node_modules folder to my gitignore through the following methods:

Adding: node_modules/ to my gitignore file
Writing: echo node_modules >> .gitignore through my terminal
Adding a separate gitignore file within my node_modules file with a * in it

None of them have worked and I can't find any other solutions. For reference I'm using a Mac.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong, or how it'd be best to do it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, you do not need to include the node_modules folder in your repositories because the package.json file contains all of your project's dependency information. This means that anyone who clones your repository can run `npm install` and have the entire node_modules folder without problems.

To solve this you can create your own .gitignore file, creating a new file at the root of your project and renaming it to .gitignore (writing exactly that way). Then you can open it with any text editor and add `*/node_modules` to one of the lines.

This will likely solve your problem.